# how to display circletype.js text over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to put some arced text infront of an image. The text keeps displaying below the image however and not ontop of it. I have tried messing around with the css and the top  alignment and the position elements with no avail.

Note it  works when I dont use circleType

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="image" >
    <img id="sticker" src="MCNSticker.jpg">
        <h2 id="stickerText">13 Characters</h2>
            <script>
                $('#stickerText').circleType({radius: 2000});
            </script>   
    </img>
</div>
<form  onsubmit="return false" onclick=displayText()>
        Input car name here:  
        <input id="carName" type="text" name="lastname" value="Enter name">
        <input type="button" value="Submit">

</form>

<script>
    function displayText(){
    var carname     =document.getElementById("carName").value;
    var carSticker  =document.getElementById("stickerText");
        if(carname.length>13){
            alert("Car name too long");
        }else{
            carSticker.innerHTML = carname;
            $('#stickerText').circleType({radius: 2000});
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.image { 
       position: relative; 
       width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
    }


h2 {    
   position: absolute; 
   top: 100px; 
   width: 1000px; 
   font-family: komika_axisregular;
   letter-spacing: 7px;
   font-size: 70px;
   text-align:center;
   color: black;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

form{
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code in fiddle.net ?

Comment: have a look on css parameter position top left and z-index. you have to assign all 4 parameters